# Prevent writing clone method for each subclass

Tags: c++

Here is my case:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual A* clone() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
    virtual B* clone() override
    { 
        return new B();
    }
};
```

In my code now 100% of sublcasses of `A` just implement the `clone` method exactly the same way only for class `D` I have return type `D` and I create object of `D` of course.

How can I prevent this duplication? What patterns or tricks can help?

I have thought to use [CRTP pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), but it uses templates, and my function is virtual. As we understand templates and virtual functions are incompatible.

[NVI pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern) does not work either, as return type of clone methods are different.

Comment: You can use CRTP, templates and virtual functions are not incompatible per se.

Comment: Maybe you can't, I'm unsure whether you can use inheritance to satisfy pure virtual functions. That's still independent of templates though. Maybe you can get around that by not using multiple inheritance but rather using an intermediate class, i.e. `class B: public clonable<A, B>{...}` and `template<class B, class D> class clonable: public B {...}`.

Comment: What is your duplicate code ? The definition of the clone methods in each subclass with only the new T call ? Or is it a bigger code in the clone methods in your real project ? If it's the second case, you can simply have a template function which clone an object and call this template function from your clone methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[class.virtual]/8:

> If the class type in the covariant return type of `D::f` differs from
>   that of `B::f`, the class type in the return  type of `D::f` shall be
>   complete at the point of declaration of `D::f` or shall be the class
>   type `D`.

So CRTP cannot work perfectly, since the template argument which refers to the derived class would be an incomplete type, and thus covariant return types are difficult to simulate.

However, here's a try:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual A* clone() = 0;
};

namespace detail {
    template <typename T>
    struct Cloner : A {
        using A::A; // For constructors
        virtual A* clone() override {return new T;}
    };
}

template <typename T>
struct Cloner : detail::Cloner<T> {
    using detail::Cloner<T>::Cloner; // For constructors

    // For callers 
    template <class=void>
    T* clone() {return static_cast<T*>(detail::Cloner<T>::clone());}
};

class B : public Cloner<B>
{
};
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b795df8721877a8).

Note two things:

- The overload of `clone` returning a pointer to the derived class type is a function template. That's so we don't override the virtual function `clone`: If we would, the code would be ill-formed, because the return type is not covariant (see above).
- Because `clone` is a function template, to ensure that it get's called at all, we can to let it hide the virtual `clone` function. That's achieved via inheritance: Names in derived classes hide names in base classes. Thus if we call through a `B`-pointer/reference, we get the appropriate return type (`B*`), since the name is looked up in `::Cloner` before `detail::Cloner`.

Comment: Why do we need second `struct Cloner`? Also why we need `template <class=void>`. Maybe you could give some small explanations. Thanks.

Comment: @Narek 1. Name hiding 2. Not overriding.

Comment: I a not that good at C++ to understand in two words, sorry. Would appreciate more detailed explanation, please.

Comment: @Narek I added an explanation.